# JS Math setinterval a random number from a range

Tags: javascript

I have a default number and after the page loads, after each second, I have to add to it a number from this range: (0.02 - 0.006).

Here is the code:

```js
var amount = 44522.1234;
setTimeout(start, 1000);

var i = Math.floor(Math.random() * (0.02 - 0.006) + 0.006);
console.log("initial" + i);
var num = document.getElementById('total');

function start() {
  setInterval(increase, 1000);
}

function increase() {
  if (i < amount) {
    i++;
    console.log(i);
    num.innerText = amount + i;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="total"></div>
```

The above code only increments the amount by `1` each second, instead of by a number in the specified range.

Comment: I'm not sure how you would ever add 1.  `Math.random()` returns a decimal value less than 1.  And you are multiplying it by `0.02`, which would never increase it above 1.

Comment: There's no need for `setTimeout` just call `start` normally or use the `setInterval` directly. Your `Math.floor` call will always floor down your range to 0 (because that's what it does). Your interval is also adding 1 instead of a number in that range.

Comment: `i++` is equivalent to `i = i + 1`. There's the 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Math.floor` will truncate the number, so it will never be in the range you want. Also, you should generate a new random number every second instead of incrementing the originally generated number.

```js
var amount = 44522.1234;
setTimeout(start, 1000);

var num = document.getElementById('total');

function start() {
  setInterval(increase, 1000);
}

function increase() {
  var i = Math.random() * (0.02 - 0.006) + 0.006;
  console.log("adding",i);
  amount += i;
  num.textContent = amount;
}
```

```html
<div id="total"></div>
```